# Outlook VBA to send Automated email with PDF attachment

Tags: vba, outlook, office-automation

Need help sending an automated email in outlook using VBA while attaching a PDF from a folder location. Below is what I have thus far. I'm stuck on the part to attach the PDF

```
Sub ViolationProcessingTest()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "<BODY style = font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
"Hello, <br><br> Please process the attached violations."

On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "email@email.com"
        .CC = "email@email.com"
        .Subject = "Violations Processing"
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = strbody & .HTMLBody
        .Attachments.Add = "Folder path location with PDF"
    
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
Set OutMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you pass a file path to the `Add` method? What is the actual value passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is a good idea to get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` line - errors are raised for a reason, otherwise you won't even know why or where your code is failing.

Secondly, your code is almost OK, you just need to get rid of `=` (it is a method call, not a property assignment) and specify a fully qualified PDF file name:

```
.Attachments.Add "c:\SomeFolder\TheFile.PDF"
```

Comment: i made those changes, and the email itself works. Attaching the PDF is still a mystery. i now have an error saying the "Path does not exist"

Comment: What is the exact value passed to `Attachments.Add`? It usually means what is says - the path cannot be found.

Comment: `        .Subject = "Violations Processing"
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = strbody & .HTMLBody
        .Attachments.Add "FilePath\ActualPDF.pdf"`

Comment: You need to specify the full file path, not relative.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer posted here.

Comment: Is `"FilePath\ActualPDF.pdf"` the actual value? It cannot possibly be right - it does not include the drive letter, like `"c:\SomeFolder\TheFile.PDF"`

Comment: it's not, it would be "F:\\wgvp-fsho01\EQ-PURCH\example\example1\example2\example3\example4\THEN_THE_PDF.PDF" but I still come back with an error

Comment: You have a double `\\` in the value. If you paste that value in the address bar in Windows Explorer, does it open the file?

Comment: nope it does not. I just tried right clicking on the PDF itself to copy the path and that doesn't even work lol

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

The [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method (not a property) ceates a new attachment in the Attachments collection. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment. So, the code should like that:

```
    With OutMail
        .To = "email@email.com"
        .CC = "email@email.com"
        .Subject = "Violations Processing"
        .HTMLBody = strbody & .HTMLBody
        .Attachments.Add filePathToYourFile
        .Display
    End With
```

You may find the [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/) article helpful.